# MySQL custom output on some values

Tags: mysql, sql, database, subquery

I have two problems that I am having trouble solving.

1. Display the difference between the values of two cells from different tables
2. Display a custom output based on the number of rows returned in a subquery and/or the value of a cell

In this specific case, I have several tables that need to be joined and combined with the custom outputs in a single MySQL query.

The tables stripped of non-essential columns and with fake data are:

```
transactions
+----+-------------+------------+--------+
| id | vendor_id   | payment_id | amount |
+----+-------------+------------+--------+
| 1  | 12          | 45         | 25     |
| 2  | 13          | 46         | 50     |
| 3  | 14          | 47         | 50     |
| 4  | 15          | 48         | 50     |
+----+-------------+------------+--------+

vendors
+-----+-------------+
| id  | vendor_code |
+-----+-------------+
| 12  | abc123      |
| 13  | efg321      |
| 14  | hjk456      |
| 15  | fed789      |
+-----+-------------+

payments
+-----+-------+--------+
| id  | order | amount |
+-----+-------+--------+
| 45  | 0032  | 25     |
| 46  | 0063  | 50     |
| 47  | 0073  | 50     |
| 48  | 0087  | 50     |
+-----+-------+--------+

refunds
+----+----------------+--------+
| id | transaction_id | amount |
+----+----------------+--------+
| 65 | 2              | 10     |
+----+----------------+--------+

properties
+-----+----------+
| id  | group_id |
+-----+----------+
| 100 | 222      |
| 200 | 333      |
+-----+----------+

vendor_properties
+----+-------------+------------+
| id | property_id | vendor_id  |
+----+-------------+------------+
| 1  | 100         | 12         |
| 2  | 200         | 12         |
| 3  | 100         | 13         |
| 4  | 200         | 14         |
+----+-------------+------------+

groups
+-----+---------+
| id  | name    |
+-----+---------+
| 222 | groupA  |
| 333 | groupB  |
+-----+---------+
```

The following relationships exist:

```
transactions.payment_id -> payments.id
transactions.vendor_id -> vendors.id
payments.vendor_id -> vendors.id
refunds.transaction_id -> transactions.id
properties.property_group_id -> groups.id
vendor_properties.property_id -> properties.id
vendor_properties.vendor_id -> vendors.id
```

My current SQL query is:

```
SELECT
    `transactions`.`id` AS DB_transID,
    `transactions`.`vendor_id` AS DB_vendID,
    `vendors`.`vendor_code` AS "VendorCode",
    `payments`.`order` AS "Order",
    `transactions`.`amount` AS "Amount"
    `refunds`.`amount` AS "Refunded",
    `groups`.`name` AS "Group"
FROM
    `transactions`
LEFT JOIN
    `payments` ON `payments`.`id` = `transactions`.`payment_id`
LEFT JOIN
    `vendors` ON `vendors`.`id` = `transactions`.`vendor_id`
LEFT JOIN
    `refunds` ON `refunds`.`transaction_id` = `transactions`.`id`
LEFT JOIN
    `groups` ON `groups`.`id` IN
    ( 
        SELECT `group_id` FROM `properties` WHERE `id` IN
        ( 
            SELECT `property_id` FROM `vendor_properties`
            WHERE `vendor_id` = @refID
        )
     );
```

The output is:

```
+------------+-----------+------------+-------+--------+----------+--------+
| DB_transID | DB_vendID | VendorCode | Order | Amount | Refunded | Group  |
+------------+-----------+------------+-------+--------+----------+--------+
| 1          | 12        | abc123     | 0032  | 25     | NULL     | groupA |
| 1          | 12        | abc123     | 0032  | 25     | NULL     | groupB |
| 2          | 13        | efg321     | 0063  | 50     | 10       | groupA |
| 3          | 14        | hjk456     | 0073  | 50     | NULL     | groupB |
| 4          | 15        | fed789     | 0087  | 50     | NULL     | NULL   |
+------------+-----------+------------+-------+--------+----------+--------+
```

What I would like to do is:

1. Add a column "Net" that contains the value of ( Amount - Refunded )
2. When a transaction has more than one Group as in transaction 1, instead of creating two rows I would like a single row with "groupA, groupB" in the Group column. And when Group is NULL, the value should be "None". The Group names list should be deduplicated. For example, if groupA appears in three transactions and group B in two transactions, the output would be "groupA, groupB".
3. When Refunded is NULL the value should be "0"

So the desired output would be:

```
+------------+-----------+------------+-------+--------+----------+-----+----------------+
| DB_transID | DB_vendID | VendorCode | Order | Amount | Refunded | Net | Group          |
+------------+-----------+------------+-------+--------+----------+-----+----------------+
| 1          | 12        | abc123     | 0032  | 25     | 0        | 25  | groupA, groupB |
| 2          | 13        | efg321     | 0063  | 50     | 10       | 40  | groupA         |
| 3          | 14        | hjk456     | 0073  | 50     | 0        | 50  | groupB         |
| 4          | 15        | fed789     | 0087  | 50     | 0        | 50  | None           |
+------------+-----------+------------+-------+--------+----------+-----+----------------+
```

*In real life, there are several thousand rows in most of these tables. As a bonus question, tell me why I sometimes get NULL for Group even when the data is such that there should be a value?*

Any additional improvements to the query would be welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is my first approach to your goals, I will update if I found any improvement:

```
SELECT
    t.id AS DB_transID,
    t.vendor_id AS DB_vendID,
    t.amount AS Amount,
    v.vendor_code AS VendorCode,
    p.order AS "Order",
    IFNULL(r.amount, 0) AS Refunded,
    IFNULL(t.amount, 0) - IFNULL(r.amount, 0) AS Net,
    IFNULL((
     SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT g.name SEPARATOR ', ')
     FROM vendor_properties vp
     LEFT JOIN properties pr ON pr.id = vp.property_id
     LEFT JOIN groups g ON g.id = pr.group_id
     WHERE vp.vendor_id = t.vendor_id
     GROUP BY vp.vendor_id
    ), "None") AS "Groups"
FROM
    transactions t
LEFT JOIN
     payments p ON p.id = t.payment_id
LEFT JOIN
     vendors v ON v.id = t.vendor_id
LEFT JOIN
     refunds r ON r.transaction_id = t.id;
```

An improvement to the previous query will be this, also if some of your foreign keys don't allow NULL values, then the `LEFT JOIN` between the related tables can be done using `INNER JOIN`:

```
SELECT
    t.id AS DB_transID,
    ANY_VALUE(t.vendor_id) AS DB_vendID,
    ANY_VALUE(t.amount) AS Amount,
    ANY_VALUE(v.vendor_code) AS VendorCode,
    ANY_VALUE(p.order) AS "Order",
    IFNULL(ANY_VALUE(r.amount), 0) AS Refunded,
    IFNULL(ANY_VALUE(t.amount), 0) - IFNULL(ANY_VALUE(r.amount), 0) AS Net,
    IFNULL(GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT g.name SEPARATOR ', '), "None") AS "Group"
FROM
    transactions t
LEFT JOIN
    payments p ON p.id = t.payment_id
LEFT JOIN
    vendors v ON v.id = t.vendor_id
LEFT JOIN
    refunds r ON r.transaction_id = t.id
LEFT JOIN
    vendor_properties vp ON vp.vendor_id = t.vendor_id
LEFT JOIN
    properties pr ON pr.id = vp.property_id
LEFT JOIN
    groups g ON g.id = pr.group_id
GROUP BY
    t.id
```

Hope this helps you, you can play with the working example here:

[DB-Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/jrc5z2Hn6AxDJht51o3nXV/2)

Comment: Thanks! This gets me 95% of the way there. For the other 5%, I should have been more clear in my description that the group names should be deduplicated. For example, if groupA appears in three transactions and group B in two transactions, the Group field would be "groupA, groupB". Also having a space between the values. (not: "groupA,groupB") I'll edit the question to include the deduplication requirement.

Comment: That is an easy fix, you just have to add `IFNULL(GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT g.name SEPARATOR ' '), "None") AS "Group"`. I will update the answer.

Comment: Great! I just found DISTINCT right as you were responding. Added SEPARATOR per your suggestion and output is perfect. (but used `', '` instead of `' '`.) `IFNULL(GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT g.name SEPARATOR ', '), "None") AS "Group"`